# change highlight of keyword in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting, regions

I would like to change the syntax highlight colour of existing keynames: #region, #endregion from blue to other colour. 
This is Visual Studion 2008 Professional Edition C# 
If colour would expand also after #region and include region name that would be even better

@Imposible with Microsoft VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colours can be configured in the Options dialog - the "Fonts and Colors" section in the Environment group lets you configure all sorts of colours, but it sounds like you want to fiddle with the "Preprocessor Keyword" colour.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but it change colour for all kaynames from preprocessor group, and I want only this two. anyway thank you for answer.

Comment: In which case, no, you cannot do what you want with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Visual Studio 2013, but I think it should be the same.
In Visual Studio, in the menus, go to:
Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors
And change the color of
"Preprocessor Keyword"
To the one you like.